# Definition of open set in Zariski Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm being confused by the definition of the open set in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry I. He says that in p.23:

"Let $X\subset A^n$ be a closed subset of affine space. We say that $U\subset X$ is open if its complement $X∖U$ is closed."

how is this differ from the definition of usual Zariski Topology (taking complement in $A^n$ instead of $X$)?

Also note that using this definition of open set, Shafarevich proved that (p.36) the set of points for which a given rational map is regular forms a nonempty and open set.

How do we say about morphism using this definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't differ - this is just the [subspace topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on $X$.

Given a topological space $A$ and a subset $B\subseteq A$, we can give $B$ the subspace topology.

Let us suppose $B$ is a closed subset of $A$.

Because we have made $B$ into a topological space via the subspace topology, we speak of subsets of $B$ being open or closed.

By the definition of the subspace topology, $C\subseteq B$ is open in $B$ if and only if there exists some $E\subseteq A$, that is open in $A$, such that $E\cap B = C$.

By the definition of "closed", the complement of $E$ in $A$, namely $A\setminus E$, is a closed subset of $A$.

Because $A\setminus E$ and $B$ are both closed subsets of $A$, their intersection $(A\setminus E)\cap B$ is also a closed subset of $A$.

Their intersection is equal to $B\setminus (B\cap E)=B\setminus C$.

Thus, $C\subseteq B$ is open in $B$ if and only if $B\setminus C$ is a closed subset of $A$.

---

In this case, $A=\mathbb{A}^n$ is affine space with the Zariski topology, $B=X$, and $C=U$.

In the quote from Shafarevich, at the end there appears "$X\setminus U$ **is closed**", which can be ambiguous when it is said without reference to *which topological space* it is closed in. However, it is implicitly being taken to mean in the big space, i.e. $A$.

Comment: I can't understand your argument about existence of $D$. But, I think If we let $X$ to be subspace topology, then the set $U$ is open in $(X,\tau_X)$ if and only if $U=X \cap D$ for some $D$ open in $(\mathbb{A}^n,\tau)$. Since $X$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$, we can't say that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{A}^n$ (unless there's special thing in our topological space)
thanks for guidance.

Comment: @Ajat - I have added an alternative explanation, and tried to explain the steps. There is nothing that depends specially on $\mathbb{A}^n$ - this is a completely general argument. If you are still unsure let me know.

Comment: Dear Zev, Thanks for your explaination :)